# scroll bar disappearing in Firefox on MacOSx?

Tags: macos, firefox

This is a weird problem that I am having with firefox on OSx.

Sometimes, in websites such as gmail and other websites, I don't have a scroll bar on the right. It just disappears, and I have to use all kind of super-manuevers with the mouse (selecting text and dragging it) in order to scroll down. I am not sure why it happens. Sometimes everything is fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [MUO (Make Use Of)](https://www.makeuseof.com/) article [5 OS X Mavericks Quirks, And How To Deal With Them](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-os-x-mavericks-quirks-and-how-to-deal-with-them/):

> In newer versions of Mac OS X, the scroll bars fade away when you're
> not actively scrolling. Ironically, the issue disappears when you
> force these fickle scrollbars to reappear. Go to *System Preferences* >
> *General* and select "Show scroll bars:" *Always*.
>
> [image: screenshot]