# Firefox scroll bar disappearing

Tags: firefox, usability, ux

Since the last update (Firefox 100), the scrollbar in Firefox fades out slowly when you don't move the mouse for a second and immediately reappears when the mouse moves one pixel. This drives me nuts as something moves on the side of text inputs or the page whenever I am trying to read something. I looked for it but found only old posts like [this support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1183512) and [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/680044/121343) that don't seem relevant.

How can this behavior be disabled? Surely there's a preference for something as annoying as this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Go to `about:preferences` or open the Firefox preferences via the UI
2. Scroll down until you get to a section titled "Browsing", or search for "scroll"
3. Check the setting "Always show scrollbars"

---

**Update:** bonus answer for **Thunderbird** which met the same fate:

1. Menu
2. Settings
3. Search "Always show scrollbars" and check it

Comment: For Windows 11 users, Firefox respects the Windows setting. Open settings app and search for "always show scroll bars" to change it.

Comment: What **exactly** is the config property name? In Firefox 108, I can't find anything like "Always show scrollbars", and there is no section called "browsing", only "browser".

Comment: @Pointy using 108.0.2: https://snipboard.io/45Aep9.jpg the name and section are **exactly** as described. Might you have a translation such as British English? In `about:config`, I think the setting is called `widget.gtk.overlay-scrollbars.enabled` (set to false to disable tiny scrollbars).

Comment: @Luc my apologies, I read "about:preferences" as "about:config", because I'd been digging around there. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: That said, my own preferences page (Firefox 108, MacOS) does not have such a selection. Maybe it's a MacOS thing. Thank you again nevertheless. *edit* yes it's a MacOS platform setting in the "Appearances" section (Ventura).

Comment: The version of firefox I have doesn't have a visible preferences menu item, so thank you for the workaround for that dis-improvement. (I'd give the version, but they also have no "about firefox" menu item. I'm on Pop!_OS Linux, which is mostly Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding this because it might help somebody. I'm on Firefox 108 (currently) on MacOS 13.1 "Ventura" (currently). Nothing I tried was working to "stabilize" the scroll bars. I finally stumbled across something MacOS-specific, and that seems to have been the issue for me. On Ventura, the setting is in `System Settings -> Appearance -> Show scroll bars`.

I'm not 100% sure but I think that might have changed to hide them with the 12->13 upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

The precise option in `about:config` that configures this behavior is (at least on Windows 11):

```
layout.testing.overlay-scrollbars.always-visible
```

Set it to `true` to always have the scrollbar visible.